# C++ Ignore Virtual File System(VFS) for specified actions with files

Tags: c++, vfs

There's an application **A** which adds Virtual file system support for application **B**.
I am writing a DLL for application **B** and I'd like to perform some actions on real(not VFS) files(check if files exist,read, write files). So basically I want some file actions to ignore VFS completely.
I am using C++ 17 filesystem library.

Is it possible to do what I want from a DLL?

Comment: This is impossible to tell - "VFS" is not anywhere near standardized. Given that **application** A adds VFS support to **application** B (i.e. not to the OS), the easiest solution in DLL C is to just ask the OS directly. (i.e. `CreateFile`). But a VFS like SMB network file sharing works on the OS level instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think app A only adds VFS support for app B since via exporer I can create new files in real folders. When I use "Create file" from DLL - file gets creared in VFS system.